# regex: find all uncommented tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, xml

i want to extract all nodes from a html or xml file which are not commented out.
The following regex is my currect approach.

**My RegEx**

```
/<span.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/gi
```

**Here the example xml**

```
<div>
<p>
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">Hello</span>
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">World</span>
</p>
<p>
    <!--
    <span>Hello</span> 
    <span>World</span>
    -->
</p>
<p>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>World</span>
</p>
<!--
<p>
    <span>Hello</span> 
    <span>World</span>
</p>
-->
```

I would appreciate help.

best regards,
Michael

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this.  Use a real XML or HTML parser.

Comment: Remove comments first, then use your approach.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: obligatory link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but unfortunately it's not possible for me to use a DOM-parser or xpath/xquery-engine in my project. That means I have to achieve the desired result with pure RegEx. :( It's also not possible to remove the comments from the source file first.

Comment: @MichaelH.: When you can use regular expressions, why can't you use a parser as well? Or is this some homework story?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove comments with a decent parser (`DomDocument` in this case) and analyze the remaining part afterwards. Consider the following code (mind the changed numbers in your `Hello World` strings to make clear what was being removed):

```
<?php

$html = '<div>
<p>
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">Hello</span>
    <span style="font-size: 20px;">World</span>
</p>
<p>
    <!--
    <span>Hello2</span> 
    <span>World2</span>
    -->
</p>
<p>
    <span>Hello3</span>
    <span>World3</span>
</p>
<!--
<p>
    <span>Hello4</span> 
    <span>World4</span>
</p>
-->
</div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment)
    $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);
echo $dom->saveXml($body);
# yields hello world and hello world3
?>
```

Now your commented tags have been removed. Obviously, you can fiddle around with the `xpath` to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks, i solved my problem with a workaround. first i extract all comments and tags and with a second regex i filter out all comments. 

/(<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<span[\s\S]*?span>)/gi